# 違うDBのテーブルを結合する方法について

Tags: mysql

お世話になっております。
同ホスト内にある異なるDBのテーブルを結合するにはどのようにしたら良いでしょうか。
テーブル情報は以下の通りです。

```
## DB作成
CREATE DATABASE DB1;
CREATE DATABASE DB2;

## Table作成
CREATE TABLE DB1.Employee (id int, name varchar(255));
CREATE TABLE DB2.Task (id int, employee_id int, name varchar(255));

## Data挿入
INSERT INTO DB1.Employee VALUES ('1', 'employee1');
INSERT INTO DB1.Employee VALUES ('2', 'employee2');
INSERT INTO DB1.Employee VALUES ('3', 'employee3');
INSERT INTO DB2.Task VALUES ('1', '1', 'task1');
INSERT INTO DB2.Task VALUES ('2', '2', 'task2');
INSERT INTO DB2.Task VALUES ('3', '3', 'task3');
```

TaskテーブルとEmployeeテーブルを結合して、Task情報にEmployeeテーブルのname属性を表示するようにしたいです。
以上、お力添えをよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

下記のように行ってみてください。

```
select DB2.Task.id, DB2.Task.name, DB1.Employee.name
from DB2.task
left join DB1.Employee
on DB2.task.employee_id = DB1.Employee.id;
```